# Combine multiple rows with different dates / variables to one row

Tags: sql, postgresql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

**I have the following data represented in a table like this:**

| User | Type | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Mobile | 2019-01-10 |
| A | Mobile | 2019-01-20 |
| A | Desktop | 2019-03-01 |
| A | Desktop | 2019-03-20 |

**Using PostgreSQL (specifically the Snowflake querying tool) - I want to achieve the following:**

| User | First_Type | First Type Initial Date | Second_Type | Second Type Initial Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Mobile | 2019-01-10 | Desktop | 2019-03-01 |

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. If that is a [homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), could you post some code, and elaborate on what have you tried so far, and where you stumbled?

Comment: No, this was not a homework question Michael.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . You can use `row_number()` (twice) and aggregation:

```
select user,
       max(case when seqnum_u = 1 then type end) as type1,
       max(case when seqnum_u = 1 then date end) as date1,
       max(case when seqnum_u = 2 then type end) as type2,
       max(case when seqnum_u = 2 then date end) as date2
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user order by date) as seqnum_u
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (partition by user, type order by date) as seqnum
            from t
           ) t
      where seqnum = 1
    ) t
group by user;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this helped tremendously! I appreciate the quick response too. There is one follow-up I did have though. 

Let's say in the original table I presented there were a bunch more records (with differing dates but overlap in the type) and now I wanted to take the first date of the first type and the *first* date of the last type. This is a bit more tricky, no? I ask because your answer gives me the first date of the second type, but if that second type switched and then back again, now I would want the first date of the last time it switched.

Comment: @Hyder . . . Then you would have a different question.  This answers the question asked here.  If you have a different question, ask a *new* question.

Comment: You're right. I've done so here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65585137/combine-multiple-rows-with-different-dates-with-overlapping-variables-to-captur

Comment: Hey Gordon ... do you know if there is a way to add the user's record count to the query? In other words, to the end result add a column that has a number for the count of records per user, in the example it would be 4.

Comment: @Hyder . . . You can add a `count(*) over (partition by user()` in either subquery, depending on whether you want the total number of rows or the total number of types.

Comment: I would want total number of rows. Don't I then also need to select it in the outer query?

Comment: @Hyder . . . Of course, but you also need to calculate the value somewhere.

Comment: What do you mean value? So in the first subquery (seqnum_u) i added "count(*) over (partition by user) as record_count" and then in the outer query i included "max(record_count) as record_count

Comment: @Hyder what if when there are multiple types or more than 100 types.. ?