# Combine multiple rows with different dates with overlapping variables (to capture first and last change dates)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following data represented in a table like this:

| User | Type | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Mobile | 2019-01-10 |
| A | Mobile | 2019-01-20 |
| A | Desktop | 2019-03-01 |
| A | Desktop | 2019-03-20 |
| A | Email | 2021-01-01 |
| A | Email | 2020-01-02 |
| A | Desktop | 2021-01-03 |
| A | Desktop | 2021-01-04 |
| A | Desktop | 2021-01-05 |

Using PostgreSQL - I want to achieve the following:

| User | First_Type | First Type Initial Date | Last_Type | Last_Type_Initial_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Mobile | 2019-01-10 | Desktop | 2021-01-03 |

So for each user, I want to capture the initial date and type but then also, on the same row (but diff columns), have their last type they "switched" to but with the first date the switch occurred and not the last record of activity on that type.

Comment: It's not clear from the question: What is the "Snowflake querying tool" for PostgreSQL?

Comment: Ignore that -- I want to accomplish this using PostgreSQL.

Comment: Oh ok. Removing the "snowflake" tag then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a `LAG` window function and conditional aggregation join via multiple CTEs and self-joins:

```sql
WITH sub AS (
  SELECT "user"
       , "type"
       , "date"
       , CASE 
            WHEN LAG("type") OVER(PARTITION BY "user" ORDER BY "date") = "type"
            THEN 0
            ELSE 1
         END "shift"
  FROM myTable 
), agg AS (
   SELECT "user"
         , MIN(CASE WHEN shift = 1 THEN "date" END) AS min_shift_dt
         , MAX(CASE WHEN shift = 1 THEN "date" END) AS max_shift_dt
   FROM sub
   GROUP BY "user"
)


SELECT agg."user"
     , s1."type" AS first_type
     , s1."date" AS first_type_initial_date
     , s2."type" AS last_type
     , s2."date" AS last_type_initial_date
FROM agg
INNER JOIN sub AS s1
  ON agg."user" = s1."user"
  AND agg.min_shift_dt = s1."date"
  
INNER JOIN sub AS s2
  ON agg."user" = s2."user"
  AND agg.max_shift_dt = s2."date"
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/FCCAY84292)</kbd>

| user | first_type | first_type_initial_date | last_type | last_type_initial_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Mobile | 2019-01-10 00:00:00 | Desktop | 2021-01-03 00:00:00 |

Comment: This worked great, thanks so much!! If I wanted to throw in a count of records for each user to the end result (in this case, user A has 9 records) - can that be amended in to the query you provided?

Comment: Great to hear and glad to help! Add any aggregate `user` calculation in `agg` CTE and `SELECT` in final query. See forked demo: https://rextester.com/RQPRQ2533

Comment: Worked perfectly! The forked demo was very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution with only windows functions and no joins:

```
with 
  prep as (
select *, 
  lag("Type") over(partition by "User" order by "Date") as "Lasttype"
from your_table_name
)
select distinct "User", 
  first_value("Type") over(partition by "User") as "First_Type", 
  first_value("Date") over(partition by "User") as "First_Type_Initial_Date", 
  last_value("Type") over(partition by "User") as "Last_Type", 
  last_value("Date") over(partition by "User") as "Last_Type_Initial_Date"
from prep 
where "Type" <> "Lasttype" or "Lasttype" is null
;
```

Comment: Ok but I do not need to create a table, i already have that. So do I remove the "prep" part?

Comment: Yes, pls remove temp table "init", and replace table "init" in the sub query "prep" with your original table name.

Comment: I don't follow. Can you please revise above?

Comment: Sure, you could replace "your_table_name" with your table name

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work, but it sure feels ugly.  There might be a better way to do this.

```
SELECT a.User, a.Type AS First_Type, a.Date AS FirstTypeInitialDate, b.Type AS Last_Type, b.LastTypeInitialDate
FROM table a
INNER JOIN table b ON a.User = b.User
WHERE a.Date = (SELECT MIN(c.Date) FROM table c WHERE c.User = a.User)
    AND b.Date = (SELECT MIN(d.Date) FROM table d WHERE d.User = b.User
       AND d.Type = (SELECT e.Type FROM table e WHERE e.User = d.User 
          AND e.Date = (SELECT MAX(f.Date) FROM table f WHERE f.User = e.User)))
```

Comment: what are tables c through f? the same table? doesn't it need to be joined?

Comment: They are for Subqueries, and they are joined by User.  Working backwards: f is for getting the maximum date.  e returns the type with the date that matches the maximum date.  d is for returning the minimum date that matches the type on the maximum date.  c is for getting only the minimum date.  For the minimum date, I could have put MIN(a.Date) in the SELECT clause, but then I would have had to add a GROUP BY, which would have added other complications.

Comment: So it's the same table just labeled c through f. I see. Here is the error i'm getting:

"SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated"